# What is the scope of the quantifier "some"?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, quantifiers

I am writing a term paper in English and am not sure which of the two sentences below is correct:

1. some apples and pears
2. some apples and some pears

What I mean to say is that there are some apples and that there also some pears. 1. seems (to me, a non-native speaker) more correct than 2. and 2. gives me the feeling that the second "some" is redundant. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: 2. Is less ambiguous, but whether that ambiguity is of concern or not is dependent on context and consequences.  1. would likely be interpreted the way you intended in most reasonable contexts.

Comment: Either is fine.

Answer (score 1):

The first is what I have used and seen in this situation. I would agree that the second "some" in the second case is superfluous to the meaning.

Comment: The second *some* is not redundant if you want to make it clear that you have two or more apples and two or more pears. Otherwise, *some apples and pears* could refer to a single apple or a single pear among a larger number of fruit.

Comment: That's true. However, if that was the case I think it would be proper to say "Some apples and a pear" or "An apple and some pears."

Comment: @Jason: That's nuts. The plural *apples* never refers to a single apple, and the same goes for *pears*. *Some* is redundant when repeated for sure, and perhaps even in a single instance. Saying "apples and pears" gets the idea across, and only if you need a limiter would you say "some apples and pears."

Comment: @Robusto The term *apples and pears* can easily apply to the combination of both things, not just the addition of one to the other. How much you get of each in the *combined group* is not defined. Most people would assume you'd get more than one of each—but you don't have to in order for it to be true. And from Merriam-Webster's definition of [*some*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/some): "being one, a part, or an unspecified number of something (such as a class or group) named or implied."

Comment: @Jason: I think you're confused about the usage of *some* here. When the dictionary says it can mean *one*, that is in the context of a singular noun, e.g., "Some idiot rang my doorbell at 3:00 a.m." In the context of a plural noun it means "more than one": "Some idiots rang my doorbell at 3:00 a.m." It simply cannot mean *one* in the latter sentence.

Comment: @Robusto No, not at all. *I would like to eat some chicken and waffles*. This doesn't say how many pieces of chicken you'll get or how many waffles you'll get. (Despite the singular and plural words in the term.) When anybody says *I'd like some X*, they don't specify a specific number; and that number can be a single measure or single quantity just as much as any other. There is nothing at all that necessitates that *some apples and oranges* be at least two of each of those individual items. If I ate *some* M&Ms, that wouldn't mean I'd have to have at least two of each colour. And so on.

Comment: @Robusto Your use of *some idiot* is a different type of grammatical construct altogether.

Comment: @Robusto I believe that what Jason is saying is that the subject here is not "apples" and "pears" but "apples and pears." An example I have heard used to illustrate this distinction, which often comes up in discussions around the Oxford comma, is "ham and eggs." This phrase can be used to mean, separately,  "ham" and "eggs," but also to mean the dish, "ham and eggs." Interestingly, when "some" is used in the first case, it's referring to an amount of ham and a number of eggs. In the second case, it only refers to an amount of "ham and eggs." I'm not sure he's right, I'm just trying to explain.

Comment: @Jason: Now you're indulging in sophistry. *Chicken* in your *chicken and waffles* usage is a mass noun, not a count noun. You might just as easily have said *some water*.  Also, I used *some idiot* deliberately to show your confusion about number. *Some pears* is the same grammatical construct as *some idiot*.

Comment: @AidanArthur: I know what Jason is saying. And "ham and eggs" is a type of meal, which would be understood as a unit in itself, which is a different grouping than "apples and pears": The essence of your question hinges on whether the fruits are taken severally or as part of such a unit.

Comment: @JasonBassford, to develop Robusto's point further: it is not just just that *chicken* is a mass term, but that the **whole** phrase *chicken and waffles* functions as a mass term. 'I would like to eat some chicken and waffles' means 'I would like to eat some unspecified quantity of the dish called "chicken and waffles"' and that is what makes it compatible with wanting to have only one waffle on one's plate. That cannot be transposed to the 'apples and pears' case.

Comment: @jsw29 Of course it can. It depends entirely on how you view the conjunction—as a mass grouping or as a simple conjunction. *"I'm going to go eat some apples and pears now." "How many of each?" "I think today I'll have one apple and two pears."* There is nothing confusing or indecipherable about that exchange.

Comment: @robusto "*Every morning I eat some pears. Some mornings, I eat three, but other mornings I eat have one.*" It's possible because it's using the *plural*. I could do the same thing with ***idiots*** (plural). *"Some* ***idiots*** *accost me every day. Sometimes as many as three, other days just one."* Your use of some ***idiot*** (singular) isn't the same thing. Nor could I use *some* ***pear*** (singular).